# how to get the nid into a views table div?

Tags: 7, views, theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically adding a CSS class to a view row with template.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/dynamically-adding-a-css-class-to-a-view-row-with-template-php)

I would like to have the node nid to be used in the DIVs of a views based table layout. When I use "style settings" / "customize field HTML" css class "divname[nid]" it has no effect (yes, I had nid added as the first field in the view ...).

What I'm trying to do is hide a div and a link in that table row when I click on links in the same table row. See my previous questions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20365/how-to-a-hide-a-link-after-clicking-on-it) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19584/how-to-remove-a-new-indicator-when-clicking-on-a-link).

Comment: This link should help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/dynamically-adding-a-css-class-to-a-view-row-with-template-php

Comment: that's it, thanks!!!. Just had to change the foreach loop to $vars['row_classes'][$id][] = 'nid'.$data->nid;